# Given the following relation between the angles of a triangle, find the number of possible triangles.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, trigonometry

If $A,B,C$ are the interior angles of triangle $\Delta ABC$ such that

$(\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)^2+(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)^2=9$, then the number of possible triangles is

$(A)0\hspace{1cm}(B)1\hspace{1cm}(C)3\hspace{1cm}(D)\infty$

---

$(\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)^2+(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)^2=\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C+2\cos A\cos B+2\cos B\cos C+2\cos C\cos A+\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C+2\sin A\sin B+2\sin B\sin C+2\sin C\sin A=9$

I do not understand how I can identify the number of possible triangles from this tedious expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)^2+(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)^2=9$$
$$\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C+2\cos A\cos B+2\cos B\cos C+2\cos C\cos A+\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C+2\sin A\sin B+2\sin B\sin C+2\sin C\sin A=9$$
$$3+2(\cos A\cos B+\cos B\cos C+\cos C\cos A+\sin A\sin B+\sin B\sin C+\sin C\sin A)=9$$
$$\cos A\cos B+\cos B\cos C+\cos C\cos A+\sin A\sin B+\sin B\sin C+\sin C\sin A=3$$
$$\cos(A-B)+\cos(C-B)+\cos(A-C)=3$$
Then

$A+B+C=\pi$ and $A=B=C \Rightarrow A=B=C=60^{\circ}$

**Answer:** $(B)$ $1$

Comment: How 60 degrees? Can't they be infinite?

Comment: In the answer,infinite is given.But i do not understand how?@AdityaAgarwal

Comment: $A=B=C=\text{any angle}$?

Comment: He got something like $\cos x+ \cos y+ \cos z=3$ This must mean they are individually all 1( recall maximum value of $\cos$) I also think the answer would be $\infty$ as there are infinite equilateral triangles.

Comment: @Nikunj, then the answer must be infinite for any type of triangle you get, because for each triangle, there are infinitely many triangles similar to it.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, if $A=B=C$ and $A+B+C=180^{\circ}$, then $A=B=C=60^{\circ}$.

Comment: @Apurv Yes, as there is no constraint on the side lengths, you are correct. However the answer could have been $0$, It may have also been possible that no such triangle existed.

Comment: Ok lol, I forgot!